# Looking for a word between many files

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, external-hard-drive, spotlight

I need to search a word in many Word documents inside many folders that are contained in an external Hard Drive on my Mac. Do you know if it is possible? thx

Answer (score 0):

[DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/download.html) should help you. It will first index all files in specified folder, then let you search them quickly. It supports plenty of file formats, including Word files.